# Pushwoosh / GCM - Android - Not receiving messages

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushwoosh

I am using Pushwoosh to implement push notifications on my native Android app.

I have followed this link: http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/native-android-sdk-integration/

When I run my app, I get the following debug messages:

```
10-09 10:09:16.529: W/DeviceRegistrar(16545): Try To Registered for pushes
10-09 10:09:16.534: W/PushWoosh DeviceFeature2_5(16545): Try To sent AppOpen
10-09 10:09:17.749: W/PushWoosh: NetworkUtils(16545): PushWooshResult: {"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":null}
10-09 10:09:17.749: V/GCMRegistrar(16545): Setting registered on server status as: true
10-09 10:09:17.754: W/PushWoosh: NetworkUtils(16545): PushWooshResult: {"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":null}
10-09 10:09:17.754: W/PushWoosh DeviceFeature2_5(16545): Send AppOpen success
10-09 10:09:17.754: W/PushEventsTransmitter(16545): No android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY. Reverting to simple broadcast
10-09 10:09:17.774: W/DeviceRegistrar(16545): Registered for pushes: APA91bEq5ihxMX7cr-qE1RLCEKF_mZf9PBGpNxerm3OhKnwk9iAnuGjDYkn3x-XR93OHJbYFOCayF7C-Q...
```

As you can see, everything seems to be ok (ie, the device is registered to receive the push messages).

After that I go to https://cp.pushwoosh.com/applications/01234-56789
Then I type a message and click on "Woosh!".

[image]

The push is sent but **I don't get anything on my device**.

Also, when I go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:0123456789:stats I can't see any data. It says "Total request: 0". **Shouldn't it be showing more than 0?**

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why am I not receiving the pushes I create?

UPDATE: I am using the latest **Pushwoosh.jar** found here: https://github.com/shaders/push-notifications-sdk/tree/master/SDK/Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have FINALLY found the problem. The firewall was blocking the ports used by GCM!

For more info, check this post: [Which port and protocol does Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571576/which-port-and-protocol-does-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-use)

Hope it helps someone! :)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks! We'll add it to the guide!

Pushwoosh team

Answer (score -2):

Hey You can easily integrate Push Notification in your Android application please follow steps of this [Project](https://github.com/shephertz/App42-Android-Push-Sample) and integrate Push Notification in your Android application