# GCM for client -getting only messages for topics

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My app seems to be properly implemented on Android; this gets the token for a specific project number as well as this subscribes the client to three different topics. The token wasn't sent to the server because it specified [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration) that for topics it is not needed, in server side, to have it.

The app server can send out the messages to the GCM server and gets the ID for the message. However, the client does not get any message. In the logging there is no information about anything. I already posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826622/gcm-client-does-not-receive-downstream-messages) with some details about my problem. Unfortunately, I did not receive any reply to my question, so I wonder if someone has implemented a client of GCM based on topics successfully and could give me a help.

Comment: Are you able to receive messages by using device registration token, you should try that first. You can get a registration token after your device is registered, then use curl or Postman to send a message to your device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help. I had a firewall restriction which was giving the limitation to receive the downstream messages. Now, my app is working fine. Just in case, this was the question that helped me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571576/which-port-and-protocol-does-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-use

Comment: Great, that StackOverflow answer is helpful.