# Studio emulator not receiving Bluemix push messages

Tags: android-studio, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

Now that I see the sample (android) application is registered for Bluemix-PUSH notifications.I have configured the Bluemix Application's info (APP ROUTE, APP UID)

I am using a Bluemix app from ----https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-hellopush. I have pulled this project, and built it with the proper dependency gradle settings.

But the problem is that I can not see the Push message sent from the Bluemix app on the emulator's push-registered Android App. Also I could not see an error in log files.

Are there any other ports that need to be opened on **Secured bank Network** in order to receive pushes from Bluemix?

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1, JDK 1.7 and Emulator - API 19 (With Google API enabled).

I built the sample application using Android API 23.0

What should we check on PUSH notifications on studio's emulator?

Comment: @Dave - I have used server Key- with Proper Google account/project details. The same sample app is working fine in Local environment & App is not able to receive pushes on a secured environment (office network).   Will emulators receive pushes on secured network or - need a firewall?
I am able to see emulator registered successfully for pushes - see log-- 
com.ibm.hellopush I/MainActivity:: Registering for notifications
com.ibm.hellopush W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10007
I can also see device ID, token etc.. here
com.ibm.hellopush I/MainActivity:: Successfully registered for push notifications

Comment: can you include your full logcat in your above question? Also, if you are successfully able to register, then your network/firewall is not the problem. Keep in mind that a push may take up to 30mins to reach the device and is not guaranteed. How are you sending the notification?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no errors anywhere, chances are that your Google app credentials have been configured using the incorrect API key.

Ensure that you have created a **Server Key** and not an **Android Key** [image]

Comment: I have used server Key- with Proper Google account/project details. The same sample app is working fine in Local environment & App is not able to receive pushes on a secured environment (office network). Will emulators receive pushes on secured network or - need a firewall? I am able to see emulator registered successfully for pushes - see log-- com.ibm.hellopush I/MainActivity:: Registering for notifications com.ibm.hellopush W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10007 I can also see device ID, token etc.. here com.ibm.hellopush I/MainActivity:: Successfully registered for push notifications.

Comment: The secured network sounds like it could be the cause. May want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571576/which-port-and-protocol-does-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-use and see if the network is blocking the ports GCM uses.