# pushnotification not received in android w.r.t. cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am working on pushnotifications w.r.t. bluemix services recently, for cordova  android application.

Toolkits used: Android 24 version, Java 8.

Steps followed: once user registered with bluemix services for push notifications w.r.t. GCM (google cloud messaging), then send push notification from the bluemix console service. Unfortunately I didn't get any of the notifications to the android device.

NOTE: I have followed steps provided from the below url:
https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush

Comment: what you had followed? codes, any errors if you get any

Comment: no errors , i am able to successfully register for push notifications event & after that try to send any messages from bluemix push notifications, those messages are not delivered to the client mobile end side, this is specific to android issue & the same app works fine for ios and able to receive messages as well.

Comment: is your pushlistener inside the application tags in your android manifest?

Comment: have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364048/studio-emulator-not-receiving-bluemix-push-messages/

Comment: yes i have verified from the device also.......to overcome emulator issues & still issue existss

Answer (score 0):

So I've just attempted to recreate your issue and ran through the sample with the latest version of Cordova (6.3.1). I'm also running the newest version of Android Studio:

[image]

There was some lag when initially sending my Push notifications (it probably took ~5-10 minutes after initial registration for me before they all started to come through).

**Before sending:**

[image: before sending]

**After sent:**

[image: after sent]

---

From your issues, on the top of my head, I think of a few things that could have potentially gone wrong:

1. There was some network latency after registration, and the Push Notifications would have eventually come through.
2. Your GCM / Push Notifications service was configured incorrectly. To test this, I would try out the [Android hellopush sample](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-hellopush) to see if I can get anything.
3. Different versions of Cordova or the emulator could be the culprit.
4. It could be something else entirely :0)

If you keep running into issues or #4 is the case, I recommend opening up a support ticket with your Push Notifications service instance. This should provide a little more of your app information to the Bluemix Mobile service team, and they should be able to look at the server logs to see what is happening to your notifications.

Comment: gcm services are deprecated, now we can make use of firebase console messaging for push notifications (fcm), is the solution as per my understanding.